# Can I create a quickbooks invoice on behalf of another user, in their account?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I am following Intuit's [oAuth authentication guide](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/authentication-and-authorization/oauth-2.0) in order to log users in through Quickbooks and get access/refresh tokens in order to make API calls. We make API calls in node through the [node-quickbooks](https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks) SDK.

I can successfully log users in through Quickbooks and exchange codes I receive for access and refresh tokens, and I can even make API calls to create invoices successfully.

The problem is, even when I use the tokens of the user I've authenticated to make API calls, the invoice is created in our Quickbooks company instead of theirs.

Is it possible to create invoices in the Quickbooks account of the other user? If not, what's the point of getting access and refresh tokens for them in the first place? For what it's worth, this is all being done in the Quickbooks developer sandbox (but with two separate accounts).

I'm quite confused as to what the methodology is supposed to be here, and any guidance would be very much appreciated -- or even just a reassurance that this is possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The QuickBooks instance that's acted on is determined by the *Realm ID* parameter. The Realm ID is captured when a QuickBooks Online account is selected during the authorization flow.

If we could call your Quickbooks company "Company A" and the one you're trying to create invoices in "Company B", I'd say it sounds like Company A's Realm ID is being logged and passed in subsequent requests instead of Company B's. This could be caused by things by hard-coding Company A's Realm ID and using that for the create invoices requests, selecting the wrong account during the authorization process, or something trickier like a bug in the SDK you're using.

I'd start by getting Company A and B's *Company ID*, which is what Intuit calls the Realm ID when you access it from the UI. You can do that while logged into a sandbox or production account by pressing **Ctrl + Alt + ?** in Windows or **Control + Option + ?** in macOS. Then you can verify the correct Realm ID is being used in the create invoice requests.

If the requests are using the value captured during authentication (as they should be), then you can —in the SDK code— log the Realm ID that's being captured during authorization and verify it's the right one for the company you selected during the OAuth flow.